# More efficient text editor for gcode insertion

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that can insert values into a text file, and am having trouble coming up with an efficient method of doing so. The goal is to have a M220 command before every change on the Z axis. The command is based on how many Z changes there are in the overall program. The idea I current have is:

```
    Take the text file, and transfer it into an array
    Read through each character to see if there is a Z
    Count the total amount of Z's
    Start at the beginning of the array
    Create a new array that copies the first one
    If a Z value is found, insert a line before it with the M220 command
    Overwrite the text file with the new array
```

This seems highly inefficient to me, especially since I am going to be dealing with txt files over 20Mb. Is there an obvious better way to do this?

Comment: 20MB is not really *that* big.  You could read a chunk of the file into memory, scan it for the Z then write the possibly modified chunks to a temp file then when you're done delete the original file and rename the temp file back to the original file name.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file line by line without the need to store the whole content in memory.

First pass: Read the file line by line and count Z's.

Second pass: Read the file line by line and write each line into a temporary file. Before writing the line check if you need to insert the new line with M220 command. If yes, then write this line before the current line.

After that you can delete the original file and copy the tempory file to the original file name.